# setup URL Destination Goals withing jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I recently tried to setup a Google Analytics URL Destination Goal which triggers on a button-click. I setup the click-event inside jQuery. The button has another click-event, which makes an ajax call but it's not important for the destination goal and I'm getting no errors at all.
When I remove some essential parts of the code I do get an error message, so the call is actually triggered.
Still it's been 3 days now and there aren't any conversions, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I hope someone can help me :)

Here are the codes:

This one's after the body opens:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

and here's the jQuery code right at the bottom of the body:

```
<script>        
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    var target = $('#button');
    target.on("click trackClick", function()
    {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "http://www.examplePage.com/toTrack"]);
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Oh yeah, the page that is tracked doesn't actually exist, but I read about it being the best solution to track a non-existing page to track button clicks.
I set the match type to "exact match" btw :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of question marks all over this. It's strange that you are using two different tracking implementations. At the top you have the newer Universal Analytics (UA) tracking snippet, but at the bottom you are using the deprecated classic GA tracking snippet to track a pageview on a click. First of all, I presume you want to track the `#button` clicks to the **same UA property**, in which case you need to remove the classic GA tracking code, and update your syntax:

```
<script>        
var target = $('#button');
target.on("click trackClick", function()
{
   // ... send your GA pageview
});
</script>
```

The second thing is that if you are certain you want to send a (virtual) pageview on the click, then you should use the UA syntax:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 'http://www.examplePage.com/toTrack');
```